# codigo que leia e imprima a media de idade em python

Tags: python

Utilizando o Python, crie um arquivo com o “seuNome.py”. Exemplo: IvoneiMarques.py
Neste arquivo, crie o código para o seguinte problema:

Faça um programa que peça para 'n' pessoas (várias pessoas - utilizando while) a sua idade,
o programa deverá verificar se a média de idade da turma
varia nos intervalos de 0 e 25,26 e 60 e maior que 60; e então, diga se a
turma é jovem, adulta ou idosa, conforme a média calculada.
Mostre também a maior idade de cada faixa.

*Obs: A digitação da idade encerra ao digitar a palavra fim, ou após digitar 40 Alunos.
Caso não haja nenhum aluno digitado em u*texto grifado*ma das faixas mostre a seguinte
mensagem: 'não houve alunos digitados*

## Exemplo:

```
Após digitar alguns alunos...
```

Digite a idade do aluno: fim

- A média de idades da Turma é: 17.5
- Portanto, pode-se dizer que a turma é Jovem.
  Para essa turma a maior idade digitada para a:
- primeira faixa é 23 anos
- segunda faixa é 33 anos
- terceira faixa não houve alunos digitados.

Meu problema está na parte da OBSERVAÇÃO

```
qtd = int(input("Quantidade de alunos: "))
i = 0
somaIDD = 0
while i < qtd:
    idd = int(input("Informe a idade: "))
    somaIDD = somaIDD + idd
    i += 1
    mediaIDD = int(somaIDD / qtd)
print ("A média das idades da turma é de: ", mediaIDD)
if mediaIDD >= 0 and mediaIDD  <= 25:
    print ("A turma é jovem")
elif mediaIDD > 25 and mediaIDD  <= 60:
    print ("A turma é adulta")
else :
    print ("A Turma é idosa")
```

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a observação, seu programa deverá encerrar quando alguém digitar '*fim*'. Porém, você está convertendo a idade para inteiro imediatamente ao ler. Com isso, sempre que digitar '*fim*', você receberá o erro.

Para cumprir com esse requisito, antes de converter a idade, receba a entrada como `string`, verifique se não é o texto desejado e só então converta para inteiro.

O exemplo abaixo faz algo nesse sentido, mas lembre-se que o tratamento de erro deve considerar todos os casos possíveis.

```py
qtd = int(input("Quantidade de alunos: "))
i = 0
somaIDD = 0
while i < qtd:
    #na linha abaixo, você recebe a idade como string e ...
    entrada_idade = input("Informe a idade: ")
    #  ... compara com o valor 'fim' ...
    if(entrada_idade == "fim"):
      # ... caso seja igual, para o loop
      break
    idd = int(entrada_idade)
    somaIDD = somaIDD + idd
    i += 1

mediaIDD = int(somaIDD / i) #calculando a média e dividindo pelas idades informadas
print ("A média das idades da turma é de: ", mediaIDD)
if mediaIDD >= 0 and mediaIDD  <= 25:
    print ("A turma é jovem")
elif mediaIDD > 25 and mediaIDD  <= 60:
    print ("A turma é adulta")
else :
    print ("A Turma é idosa")
```

Outro detalhe: você estava calculando a média no loop, ou seja, `n` vezes, isso é desnecessário.
Mais um detalhe: você estava dividindo pela quantidade informada inicialmente e não pelo número de idades recebidas.